# Create Table in MySQL using Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to dynamically create a Table in MySQL from Node.js

```
con.query('CREATE TABLE ?', req.params.username + '(id INT(100) NOT NULL
AUTO_INCREMENT, name TINYTEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id))', function (err, result) {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                        else console.log('Table created ' + result);
                    });
```

When the query is hard-coded like ,

```
con.query('CREATE TABLE Sample (id INT(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name 
TINYTEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id))', function (err, result) {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                        else console.log('Table created ' + result);
                    });
```

It works.

So, my question is how to create a table dynamically ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use a parameterized query to substitute a table name. You Can't Do That™. You can't do it with column names either.

You need to write code containing a text string with your data-definition language without `?` parameters and then run it.  That's easy to do with string manipulation in JS.

```
var tableDef = 'CREATE TABLE '+ req.params.username + ' (id INT(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name TINYTEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id))';
con.query(tableDef, ...etc )
```

Comment: Be sure to sanitize req.params.username before concatenation, as this is currently vulnerable to SQL injection